# gradient in to circle

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head> 

<body>
    <canvas id="mycanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black;">
        upload yor browser old man!
    </canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
        var cxt = c.getContext( "2d" );

        grad = cxt.createLinearGradient( 0 , 0 , 200 , 200 );

        grad.addColorStop( 0 , "blue" );
        grad.addColorStop( 1 , "green" );

        cxt.fillStyle = grad;
        cxt.arc( 400 , 300 , 250  , 0 , Math.PI * 2 , true );
        cxt.fill();
    </script>

</body>
```

im trying to put the gradient in to the circle, the problem is the circle is just green the gradient loose the blue color or maybe the gradient is not working. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your gradient ends before your circle starts :

```js
        var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
        var cxt = c.getContext( "2d" );

        grad = cxt.createLinearGradient( 0 , 0 , 200 , 200 );

        grad.addColorStop( 0 , "blue" );
        grad.addColorStop( 1 , "green" );

        cxt.fillStyle = grad;
        cxt.rect(0,0,c.width, c.height);
        cxt.fill();
        cxt.strokeStyle = "#000";
        cxt.arc( 400 , 300 , 250  , 0 , Math.PI * 2 , true );
        cxt.fill();
        cxt.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    </canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. i  really appreciate. im starting in this.

Answer (score 0):

Your gradient is working fine..

try changin the gradient starting and ending coordinates, like...

```
grad = cxt.createLinearGradient( 275, 175, 525, 425);
```

.. so that the gradient lies within the circle.

Comment: it's great if it helped!